# Mule ESB Dataweave type cast from string to date format

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have one date field - `ddmmyyyy` and I want to convert it to date format `YYYY-MM-DD T00:00:00`. I have tried with as :date and also with local date then date - as: loacaldate as date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataWeave Date which is defined between '|' must follow the [ISO-8601 standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Another thing is, I still unable to put a dynamic value on it, e.g.: `|payload.origDate|`.

For this issue, the following script working properly at my machine:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    formattedDate: (payload.origDate as :date {format: "ddMMyyyy"}) as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00"}
}
```

Notes: payload.origDate is a String "31032016"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
%dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 %type mydate = :string { format: "YYYY-MM-DD T00:00:00" }
 ---
{
formatedDate1: |31032016| as :mydate,
}
```